# How to get multiple label value using jquery & push into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jsp

I need to create a label tag by iterating a list from database, it's work fine
I need to get those values & push into array.

jsp code //this return three values eg: room1 , room2, room3

```
<c:forEach var="roomOccupanice" items="${RoomOccRequestNow}">

<label value ="${roomOccupanice}"  class="roomOccupanice" id="roomOccupanice">${roomOccupanice}</label>

 </c:forEach>
```

.js code

```
  var roomOcc = []

    $(".roomOccupanice").each(function(){

            var label = $("#roomOccupanice").text();
            alert($("#roomOccupanice").text());
            roomOcc.push(label);

        });
```

alert & array(roomOcc) only fill with room1, 
roomOcc =[room1, room1, room1] but i need like this roomOcc =[room1, room2, room2]

clarify this.

Comment: use 'this' insted of '#roomOccupanice'

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(this)` reference to get current element text in loop

Try this

```
    $(".roomOccupanice").each(function () {

    var label = $(this).text(); // It will get current label text
    alert($(this).text());
    roomOcc.push(label);

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this)` to get reference of current object in `.each()`.

```
 $(".roomOccupanice").each(function(){

        var label = $(this).text();
        alert($(this).text());
        roomOcc.push(label);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use .each() function so it repeats on the Elements which wrote before .each() i.e
    $(".roomOccupanice") //jQuery Selector

if there are let say in your case three elements, then .each() will repeat 3 three times, each time you want to referer to the current item , use $(this) and you can also have its counter.
By using this:

```
$(".roomOccupanice").each(function(loopcounter){
alert(loopcounter);
});
```

it display something like this:
0
1
2

Answer (score -1):

You can use **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** to shorten your code as well:

```
var roomOcc = $('.roomOccupanice').map(function(i, el) {
    return $(el).text();
});
```

Also note that `id` is unique, you should remove `id="roomOccupanice"` from your `<label>`